# Define download size for wget or curl

Tags: bash, curl, download, wget

As part of a bash script I need to download a file with a known file size, but I'm having issues with the download itself.  The file only gets partially downloaded every time.  The server I'm downloading from doesn't seem particularly well set up - it doesn't report file size so wget (which I'm using currently) doesn't know how much data to expect.  However, I know the exact size of the file, so theoretically I could tell wget what to expect.  Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?  I'm using wget at the moment but I can easily switch to curl if it will work better.  I know how to adjust timeouts (which might help too), and retries, but I assume that for retries to work it needs to know the size of the file its downloading.

I have seen a couple of other questions indicating that it might be a cookie problem, but that's not it in my case.  The actual size downloaded  varies from <1Mb to 50Mb, so it looks more like some sort of lost connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you share the entire command to check what parameters are you using? however, it's a strange case.
You may use the **-c** parameter, restore the connection in the same point where it stopped after the retries.
Or you can try using **--spider** parameter. That checks if the file exists and get the info file in log.

Comment: I have no idea why, but using `-c` worked!  Once I added it it recognised the file size on the server.